# Русские символы не записываются файл

Tags: c++, вывод, файлы, ввод

```
bool addCategory(const std::wstring& name_category)
{
wfstream fio = initAndCheckWFSTREAM(FILENAME_CATEGORY, ios_base::app |       ios_base::out); // инициализация fio (своя функция с некоторыми особенностями)

if (isFileEmpty(FILENAME_CATEGORY))
fio << "[Список категорий]:\n";

fio << name_category << "\n"; 
return true;
```

}

Оператор *fio << name_category << "\n"* не выполняется, соответственно никакого вывода нет и fio.fail присваивается true. В чем проблема, можно было бы грешить если бы я не создал wstring, wfstream, но по смыслу вроде бы все правильно. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

записывайте правильно

```
fio << L"[Список категорий]:\n";
```

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, но дело не в этом. И с этой записью ничего не меняется.

Comment: @dbs1024: А вывод чего-то другого, например, числа, работает? `fail` устанавливается _только_ после вывода строки?